# Consuming SAML2.0 Token

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0

We have a third party that redirects their users to our site. Currently they pass the user authentication information in an encrypted string.

Now they want us to support SAML2.0 tokens. How easy or difficult it is to use WIF for this requirement? what other (free) solutions should I look into? Any pointers to article or code samples to the same is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consume *Saml2 tokens* their is built in support in the .NET framework for that, look at the [Saml2Assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.saml2assertion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Saml2SecurityTokenHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.saml2securitytokenhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes.

If you want your application to become a full SAML2 Service Provider you have to use an external library. A free implementation that provides basic functionality (which should be enough from the scenario you describe) is [Kentor.AuthServces](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) ([Nuget package for mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc/)).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by - "full SAML2 service provider". We want to be able to consume SAML2 token when it is IdP initiated SSO. And we also want to be able to initiate authentication request.

Comment: There are other protocols that use the SAML2 token format, in that case you don't need to have an SP implementation. But now you want to communicate with an Idp, which means your app will become an SP. The Kentor.AuthServices package should work for you out of the box (it is currently limited to using only one Idp, but that seems to be your situation).

Comment: I read WIF now supports both SAML2 tokens and SAML2 protocol. Is that not correct?

Comment: WIF as a separate framework is deprecated, it is part of Core .NET from 4.5 and onwards. There was a preview of SAML2 protocol support for WIF, but it was never released and didn't make it into the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article really useful when I was looking into using SAML 2.0 tokens. Comes with good code samples

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504399/Understanding-Windows-Identity-Foundation-WIF